# Compilation errors with Script task in ssis even though there are no errors with Script in visual studio

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, interop

I need to copy a sample excel worksheet with specified format and save it in the same excel file with different name using c# i had scripted like this

```
String file = "C:\\Users\\Aditya\\Downloads\\Destinations\\DataDicWithFormating.xlsx";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = null;
        excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(file, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheets = workbook.Worksheets;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(2);


        // Copy the source sheet
        Object defaultArg = Type.Missing;

        sheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
        sheet.UsedRange.Copy(defaultArg);

        // Paste on destination sheet
        sheet2.UsedRange._PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);

        workbook.Save();
        workbook.Close();
        excel.Quit();
```

it throws compilation errors I cant find whats wrong with the script, could some one please help me with this.

Thank in Advance

Adithya.

Comment: What error is thrown and where? Did you try debugging it?

Comment: It says "Scripts contained in the package have compilation errors" when i try to save it in the script task of an ssis package

Comment: You first have to find out, where the compilation error exactly occurs.

Comment: Only AFTER it compiles :-)

Comment: Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.InvokeMember'  this was the error poping out in the error list

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you with that. I would suggest you get a proper development environment up and running, try a few basic examples to make sure the system itself works and the post the full source code of a minimalistic example that shows your exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio with the C# code open (not the Visual Studio window with SSIS open), go to **Project > Add Reference > Assemblies > Microsoft.CSharp**.  This was happening for me too when a Worksheet was being referenced, and adding this reference fixed it.